# how to count number of japanese and latin characters in a string?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function that properly follows Japanese counting of characters and therefore returns length of characters in a string given these conditions:

- 1 for Full-width char (Japanese kanji, katakana, and hiragana)
- 0.5 for Half-width char (0-9, A-Z).

here is my unit test I wrote:

```js
  describe('#getCaptionLength', () => {
    it('should return correct caption length for japanase', () => {
      const text = 'を取り外すコネクタと考えてください';
      const result = getCaptionLength(text);
      expect(result).toBe(17)
    });

    it('should return correct caption length for japanase mixed with latin', () => {
      const text = 'を取り外すコネクタと考えてください hello world';
      const result = getCaptionLength(text);
      expect(result).toBe(17 + 6);
    });
  });
```

Can you please help me write this function that would pass my unit test?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very complicated if you want to just pass these two tests you could write something like this:

```js
function getCaptionLength(text) {
    // find all latin characters with RexExp
    let re = new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9 ]+', 'g');
    let found = text.match(re);
    // get length of latin part
    let latinLength = found ? found.join('').length : 0;
    // japanese part is just full string - latin part
    let japaneseCharactersLength = text.length - latinLength;
    // calculate and return the final result
    return japaneseCharactersLength + latinLength * 0.5;
}
```

But this of course would also count as 1 everytihng that is not either Japanese character OR latin character such as emoji, special characters and what not.